# On anchor hover add border or box-shadow for image

Tags: html, css

I need to add border or box-shadow to image when i hover over a link. hover should show animated circle around the round image. I am using following css but it is not working.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mArEoX

```
<div class="sub-page-menu-item-w">
  <div class="sub-page-menu-img">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/0066ff/fff" class="sub-page-menu-imgx img-responsive img-circle">
  </div>
  <a href="/location/" class="sub-page-menu-a">Location</a>
</div>

.img-circle{
  border-radius:100%;
}
.sub-page-menu-a:hover ~ .img-circle {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 14px #B28164 !important;
}
.sub-page-menu-a:hover {
  color:green !important;
  font-size:18px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The general sibling selector (`~`) will not find elements that precede the element to the left of the selector. To make this work you would have to switch the order of the `sub-page-menu-a` and `sub-page-menu-img` in your HTML.

However, this still will not work as `img-circle` is not a sibling of `sub-page-menu-a`.

Working code:

```css
.img-circle{
  border-radius:100%;
}
.sub-page-menu-a:hover ~ .sub-page-menu-img .img-circle {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 14px #B28164 !important;
}
.sub-page-menu-a:hover {
  color:green !important;
  font-size:18px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-page-menu-item-w">
  <a href="/location/" class="sub-page-menu-a">Location</a>
  <div class="sub-page-menu-img">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/0066ff/fff" class="sub-page-menu-imgx img-responsive img-circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working if you move anchor after div example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xELEkq

Comment: That's correct. I explained why that is true in my answer. - _"The general sibling selector (~) **will not find elements that precede the element to the left of the selector**"_

Comment: Is there a way around to make it work by CSS as i cant move link another div

Comment: There is no CSS selector that can move backwards through the DOM.

Comment: You could add the `:hover` to a parent element - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGkGGJ

Answer (score 1):

As there is no *previous* sibling selector or a parent selector we can do a little trick here, using `flexbox` and its `order` property.

In below sample the anchor is before the image `div`/`img` group in the markup, and then their order is swapped by giving the anchor `order: 1` and its parent `display: flex`

Also, the sibling selector `~` is for siblings, not children, so it has to target the image `div`, which will target the `img`, like this `.sub-page-menu-a:hover ~ .sub-page-menu-img .img-circle`

```css
.sub-page-menu-item-w {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sub-page-menu-item-w a {
  order: 1;
}

.img-circle{
  border-radius:100%;
}
.sub-page-menu-a:hover ~ .sub-page-menu-img .img-circle {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 14px #B28164 !important;
}
.sub-page-menu-a:hover {
  color:green !important;
  font-size:18px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-page-menu-item-w">
  <a href="/location/" class="sub-page-menu-a">Location</a>
  <div class="sub-page-menu-img">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/0066ff/fff" class="sub-page-menu-imgx img-responsive img-circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work on mobile browsers.. I have to check this seem to be a very nice trick

Comment: @Learning Yes it does, check this browser support list: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox